# Stored boolean value isn't showing. - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, boolean

By reading the title, it sounds pretty straight forward, but for me, I'm doing a lot of head scratching wondering where I've gone wrong.

Rewinding some, I have a form with a list of checkboxes. The checkboxes which apply are selected and stored once the submit button is pressed.

The data is stored, no problem. I see `1`s and `0`s in the DB. However trying to fetch the value has been tricky. All I want to do is see if the Boolean value for a column equals `1` and if so, show a message to the user. That's it, but none of the Boolean values show at all. If try to see a value in a column that isn't a Boolean field, everything works fine.

HTML file:

```
{% if app.checkbox_var1 == '1' %}
    <li>
         // Message goes here.
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

I've also tried:

```
{% if app.checkbox_var1 == 1 %}
    <li>
         // Message goes here.
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

```
{% if app.checkbox_var1.value == 1 %}
    <li>
         // Message goes here.
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

```
{% if app.checkbox_var1 == True %}
    <li>
         // Message goes here.
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

Not forgetting a simple `{{ app.checkbox_var1  }} // Nothing appears`

Model.py:

All of the checkboxes are like this: 
`checkbox_var1= models.BooleanField(default=False)`

Form.py:

```
'checkbox_var1': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
     'class': '',
     'value': '1',
}),
...
'checkbox_varN': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
     'class': '',
     'value': '1',
}),
```

I welcome any advice.

Comment: what do you get the output of `{{ app.checkbox_var1 }}` in your template?

Comment: I just added it above. I get nothing at all. No values.

Comment: can you post the code of the views.py?

Comment: Why are you creating your form by passing the value *'1'*? Can't you just use the `forms.BooleanField()`?

Comment: What is `app`? You need to show your view. Is this a form or a model?